# Need to troubleshoot IDF monitor in the esp-idf for the esp32. No longer showing output

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I have the esp-idf (v3.2) set up on my MacBook and yesterday morning I was able to make, flash, and monitor a project and see the debugging output in the IDF monitor.  However, after some code changes that stopped working.  I can see that the chip is still running because it is generating the MQTT output in the code.  However, 'make monitor' has no output anymore.

I've tried reverting to earlier code where it worked but no luck.  I've also run 'make menuconfig' to look at the settings but am unsure of what I'm looking for there.

Output from 'make flash monitor':

```
...(error free compile)...
LD build/Valve32.elf
esptool.py v2.6
Flashing binaries to serial port /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART (app at offset 0x10000)...
esptool.py v2.6
Serial port /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
Connecting........_
Chip is ESP32D0WDQ5 (revision 1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, Coding Scheme None
MAC: 24:0a:c4:1c:8a:d4
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 921600
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB
Compressed 8192 bytes to 31...
Wrote 8192 bytes (31 compressed) at 0x0000d000 in 0.0 seconds (effective 8744.0 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.
Compressed 26224 bytes to 14981...
Wrote 26224 bytes (14981 compressed) at 0x00001000 in 0.2 seconds (effective 1139.3 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.
Compressed 1050416 bytes to 600114...
Wrote 1050416 bytes (600114 compressed) at 0x00010000 in 9.8 seconds (effective 861.8 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.
Compressed 3072 bytes to 135...
Wrote 3072 bytes (135 compressed) at 0x00008000 in 0.0 seconds (effective 3082.0 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
MONITOR
--- idf_monitor on /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART 115200 ---
--- Quit: Ctrl+] | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H ---
```

As you can see, I get no output anymore.  Unfortunately
I didn't grab any of the output that was there earlier.

Comment: You might have change the log level or the boot log configuraiton. Delete `sdkconfig` and run `make menuconfig` again. If that doesn't help, add the code supposed to generate output to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Press the reset(enable) button after you see:

> ***MONITOR
> --- idf_monitor on /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART 115200 ---
> --- Quit: Ctrl+] | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H ---***

Answer (score 0):

Briefly disconnecting the serial cable allowed "make monitor" to work.  I was never able to determine why, but I did notice that brand new chips worked fine for several cycles but then resorted to the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and was seeing the only text mentioned above after running "idf.py -p com7 monitor".  After doing a "idf.py fullclean" it stated an error that "Does not match the generator used previously: Visual Studio 15 2017".  I remembered that I was playing around with Cmake and make from the command line, so that is probably what caused the broken state.  It told me to remove the CMakeCache.txt and CMakeCache directory, which I did and then I rebuilt, and it started working again.  Hope this helps somebody.